# cheerio is not a function on the server with same node.js version as locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have a scraper which uses cheerio.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
$ = cheerio.load(s, { decodeEntities: true });
var sel = $('.text');
cheerio(sel).find(selector)
```

When I call it locally, it works fine. When I call it on a server with Cent OS but with the same node version (12.18.3) I use locally, I get `cheerio is not a function` error. I cleared the node_modules folder on local and remote and made `npm install` but no change. What else can cause this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that sometimes `require('packageName').default` needs to be exported. So I tried it and could fix it on the remote but locally `require('cheerio').default` wouldn't work. Now it works locally and on the server with the following solution:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
if (typeof (cheerio) != 'function') cheerio = require('cheerio').default;
```

I just don't have any idea why it's different on both machines with the same node.js version.

Comment: different cheerio version?

Comment: no it was the same cheerio version 1.0.0-rc.5